# how to recover the status of a checkbox with @ViewChild?

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a form that contains several checkboxes.
When the user checks a checkbox, leaves the form page and goes back, I want the checkbox to appear checked.

In my application this is not the case, I can not have this behavior, and the checbox initially checked by the user appear unchecked when he returns to the page

How to fix this? I tried to use @ViewChild like this, without success.

In ts (example for one checkbox):

```
      @ViewChild('checkDisability', {static: false, read: ElementRef}) public 
        checkDisability: ElementRef;

      public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.checkBoxState(this.checkDisability, 'disabilityChecked');
      }

       protected buildForm(): void {
         disabilityChecked: [false],
        });
      }
  

       private checkBoxState(checkBox: ElementRef, formControlName: string): void {
        checkBox.nativeElement.checked = this.isChecked(formControlName);
      }

     // We get the status of the checkbox
     public isChecked(formControlName: string): boolean {
       return this.form.controls[formControlName]?.value === true;
      }
```

The HTML:

```
<amp-checkbox #checkDisability
                      [formControl]=form.controls.disabilityChecked
                      [formControlName]="'disabilityChecked'"
                      [page]=page
                      (onChecked)="onCheckboxChecked('disabilityChecked')">
        </amp-checkbox>
```

With this code, I can find the status of the checkbox (false, true) in the ngAfterViewInit() method, but when the status is true (the user checked the checkbox) the checkbox is still not checked when the user returns to the page.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know your components, but at first glance it seems like it should be `(onChecked)="onCheckboxChecked($event)"` instead. And also, you don't need both `formControl` and `formControlName`. formControlName="disabilityChecked" should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to retrieve tan event, I want to recover the initial state that has not changed between the time the user checks the checkbox, he leaves the page and he comes back to it. The formControlName is an Input

Comment: You keep the checkbox value in component. So every time user navigate out of the component, the component get destroy and value is disappear. The robust way to make it is by create a service to keep the value and the checkbox retrieve the value from the service instead.